# Access crashes when reading database from the network with ms query

Tags: ms-access

so i am trying to pass time during the end of the world learning a bit of access (i already know a decent bit of sql). I am particularly interested in pulling query results made in access to use them in excel.

So far i have managed to create my database in access, populate it with data imported from excel and create the queries i need to use in excel. I have also managed to get the queries data in excel using MS Query (from "From other sources" menu because i would to query the query with parameters) and it is all peachy. It fails when i upload the access database on my work network. For some reason i can access the tables but as soon as i try to load my access query in MS query, it will just freeze to death.

I tried letting it run 20 minutes to no avail. I was wondering if anyone ever had that kind of issue. i tried several things for example i can access queries from other online database, the difference is that database is less heavy (the failing one is 100 mb) but considering i m a beginner i am not sure what else to do.

Thank you in advance

edit : i left it running and apparently it works, it's just that it takes a gazillion years : it is a sum query that runs on a 900k rows table

```
SELECT main.yearData, main.period, main.week, main.articleId, listArticles.brand, listArticles.description, groupToType.type, listArticles.model, listArticles.color, Sum(main.sales) AS totalSold, Sum(main.stock) AS totalStocks

FROM groupToType INNER JOIN (listArticles INNER JOIN main ON listArticles.articleId = main.articleId) ON groupToType.productGroup = listArticles.productGroup

GROUP BY main.yearData, main.period, main.week, main.articleId, listArticles.brand, listArticles.description, groupToType.type, listArticles.model, listArticles.color;
```

Is there anything i can do to make it run faster? i cannot wait 15 minutes every time to get the update info.7
Thank you again !

Comment: Why on earth are you passing Excel data to Access, query the data in Access and pass the data back to Excel? When processing Excel data use Excel, when querying data with Access, keep on process the data in Access.

Comment: Hello Wolfgang, as i said i am not really knowledgeable on the matter, basically i want to use an access database the same way i use a mysql database when i work in php. The idea here is to store the data in more tidy and scalable manner than just having multiple excel "database" files. Also i would like to do it that way because i am the only one in the team to have an access licence but everyone has excel. Is there a better way to do it? it seemed to make sense considering excel has microsoft query to do it (and it works great on my hard drive)

Comment: Use mysql or MS SQL, these are server applications. MS Access is not.

Comment: Hello Wolfgang, i wish i could as it would save me a lot of time but it is in corporate environment with corporate data and our data security policy doesnt allow me to be really original with all that. anyway thank you for your answers.

Comment: also for further info, even running the query inside access when the database is on the network location is very very slow it's not much faster if at all than fetching the data from excel so iam not sure that the issue in itself is the way i pull the data. when i access the main table with the 800k rows, it is available fairly fast but the query itself takes around 15 minutes